# Error "StopIteration: iteration not started" when updating row

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I get the following error when trying to update the row on a for loop where I have assigned values to the row's attributes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Arcpy_Scripts\LOS_Many_Points.py", line 39, in <module>
    cursor.updateRow(row)

StopIteration: iteration not started
Failed to execute (LOSManyPoints).
```

See below the code:

```
#Import geoprocessing.
import arcpy

#Import workspace.
arcpy.env.workspace = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf'

#Input parameters
buffer_distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#Input variables.
fc_Opt_All = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Equipment.gdb\Optimity_All'
fc_Opt_Opp = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\Optimity_Equipment.gdb\Optimity_Prospect'
fc_London_Bldngs = r'D:\ArcGIS_Pro_Projects\Optimity_Alf\London_Building.gdb\London_Buildings_Multipatch'
DSM_model = r'D:\Data4Optimimty\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM\ESRI_UK_Bluesky_DSM.gdb\DSM_25cm_2015'


arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_Opt_Opp, 'fl_Opt_Opp')
field_names = ['LOCATION', 'ESTATE', 'ADDRESS', 'OFFSETA', 'OFFSETB', 'Z', 'OFFSETC', 'AZIMUTH1', 'AZIMUTH2', 'VERT1', 'VERT2', 'RADIUS1', 'RADIUS2', 'STATUS', 'CONNECTION']
observers = []
targets = []  
#Calculating LOS for each point
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc_Opt_Opp,field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:

        #Adding default values to observers' attributes
        row[1] = 'Prospect'
        row[3] = 1
        row[4] = 0
        arcpy.AddSurfaceInformation_3d('fl_Opt_Opp', DSM_model, 'Z', 'BILINEAR')
        row[6] = row[3] + row[5]
        row[7] = 0
        row[8] = 360
        row[9] = 1
        row[10] = -16       
        row[11] = 0
        row[12] = 2000      
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: If you remove this line `arcpy.AddSurfaceInformation_3d('fl_Opt_Opp', DSM_model, 'Z', 'BILINEAR')` do you still get that error?

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Then we don't need to see that line.  Perhaps there are other lines that you can remove too.  The fewer lines that you present, while still showing the error, the likelier it is that a potential answerer will be attracted to your question.